# Magento Only product page styling is missing

Tags: magento

I am facing problem in magento since this morning and the problem is the magento product page styling is not working . everything in the website is working fine except the product page in which it is not everything is not working like the header the main content area

you can checkout the link `hub.com.pk/index.php/her/bag-1349.html`

Comment: was it working before , means yesterday? do you have any backup ?

Comment: it was working since morning but now it worked! some issue with the .htaccess

Comment: glad it worked for you, if you want you can post an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?